# MapQuickItem not visible in QML Map

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtlocation

I want to draw a circle dynamically (through C++) on a `QML` Map, But depending on the the zoomLevel, the circle may not be visible. `MapCircle` does not have a zoomLevel property. So I am first creating a `MapQuickItem` and trying to put a `MapCircle` as its `sourceItem`. in QML I have

```
function add_point(lat, lng){
    var circle = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtLocation 5.3; MapCircle { }', map, "dynamic");
    circle.center = QtPositioning.coordinate(lat, lng);
    circle.radius = 5.0;
    circle.color = 'blue';
    circle.border.width = 1;
    var item = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtLocation 5.3; MapQuickItem{}', map, "dynamic");
    item.anchorPoint.x = 2.5;
    item.anchorPoint.y = 2.5;
    item.coordinate = QtPositioning.coordinate(lat, lng);
    item.sourceItem = circle;
    item.zoomLevel = 19.0
    map.addMapItem(item);
    map.points.push(item);
    return true;
}
```

If I just draw the `MapCircle` a circle is visible on the map, However with the above code nothing appears on screen on any `zoomLevel`, I have tried removing the `zoomLevel` property, but still nothing appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapQuickItem is used to add standard QQuickItems to the map. While a MapCircle is a QQuickItem, it is not something you are supposed to put in there.
If you want to add a circle to the map by mean of MapQuickItem, you should add a Rectangle as source item, with the appropriate radius.
Both of the following approaches work

```
var item = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.7; import QtLocation 5.3; MapQuickItem{}', map, "dynamic");
item.anchorPoint = Qt.point(2.5,2.5)
item.coordinate = QtPositioning.coordinate(lat, lng);
item.zoomLevel = 10
var circle = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.7; Rectangle{ width: 32; height: 32; radius: 16}', map);
item.sourceItem = circle
map.addMapItem(item);
```

and

```
var item = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.7; import QtLocation 5.3; MapQuickItem{ sourceItem: Rectangle{ width: 32; height: 32; radius: 16}}', map, "dynamic");
item.anchorPoint = Qt.point(2.5,2.5)
item.coordinate = QtPositioning.coordinate(lat, lng);
item.zoomLevel = 10
map.addMapItem(item);
```

Keep in mind that the rectangle size means size in pixel. When you set zoomLevel to the MapQuickItem, it becomes *pixels at that zoom level*.
Meaning that at zoom level 10 the rectangle will be 32 pixels wide. At zoom level 9 it will be 16 and so on.
By the way, if you want to control the visibility depending on the zoom level, you should rather script the visible property.
Something like:

```
item.visible: map.zoomLevel > 10
```